# Dependency errors with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I installed Android Studio recently. But I have been having the following problems:

[image]

Please, can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty vague, but try following basic hints that I think might help you if you have not already followed these basic steps.

1) Update your Android Studio, if it is not up to date. 
2) Also check the settings to make sure that it is pointing at the correct location of JDK installed on your machine.
3) After this try rebooting and restart android studio.
4) Also make sure to check and install any updates you need to for current API version that you are using.